# How to ignore multiple whitespace chars and words in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern which is looking for word1 followed by word2 followed by word3 with any number of characters in between.
My file however contains many random newline and other white space characters - which means that between word 1 and 2 or word 2 and 3 there could be 0 or more words and/or 0 or more newlines randomly

Why isn't this code working? (Its not matching anything)

```
strings = re.findall('word1[.\s]*word2[.\s]*word3', f.read())
```

[.\s]* - What I mean by this - find either '.'(any char) or '\s'(newline char) multiple times(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your reg ex is not working is because reg ex-es only try to match on a single line. They stop when they find a new line character (`\n`) and try to match the pattern on the new line starting from the beginning of the pattern.

In order to make the reg ex ignore the newline character you must add `re.DOTALL` as a third parameter to the `findall` function:

```
strings = re.findall('word1.*?word2.*?word3', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!
But just on a side note - what is wrong with the [.\s]* syntax?

Comment: @shoi Since we use `re.DOTALL`, `.` will already include all whitespace

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1) `.` doesn't mean anything special inside brackets `[]`.

Change your `[]` to use `()` instead, like this: `(.|\s)`

2) `\` doesn't mean what you think it does inside regular strings.

Try using raw strings:

```
re.findall(r'word1 ..blah..')
```

Notice the `r` prefix of the string.

Putting them together:

```
strings = re.findall(r'word1(.|\s)*word2(.|\s)*word3', f.read())
```

However, do note that this changes the returned list.

Comment: Wouldn't using 'r' mean that '\s' is treated as a raw string i.e as two separate characters '\' and 's'... and not as an escape sequence signifying a whitespace character?

Comment: No. Using `r` means that `\s` is treated as a raw string, i.e. two separate characters `\` and `s`, which **is** the escape sequence signifying a whitespace character. Not using `r` means that `\s` is one character, namely `s`.